# Increment numbers starting from Zero in any cell without specific reference in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, increment

I want to increment numbers starting from Zero in any cell without specific reference in Excel without VBA. I know to use   `col()-col($A$1)`, or a helper column, a1+1, auto-fill options. They all require a reference cell which much be changed if the starting cell is changed. but I have many offset formulae which reference the same ranges but from different cells.
Essentially what I've been unsuccessfully trying to do is have the one formula to paste into any cell, named range or other formula to increment by 1 starting from zero in any cell.

I don't think it should be hard to to, but so far my search has not yielded desired results as per my requirements.(As a last resort - after looking through all the aisles 4 times in every supermarket, twice) I'm asking the question.

What I want is:

0
1
2
3
4...etc. with rows or columns. in any cell without having to reference a absolute cell because I'll have to keep changing that reference with every formula in a different cell.

```
OFFSET(payments!$E$14,,GCD((COLUMN()-COLUMN('error test'!$B$1))*5),COUNTA(OFFSET(payments!$E$14:$E$522,,GCD((COLUMN()-COLUMN('error test'!$B$1))*5))),1)
```

`(COLUMN()-COLUMN('error test'!$B$1)` - this part is just to start at 0 but I have to keep changing the reference `$B$1` whenever i put the formula into a different cell or table or pull data from another range. I have many like this, each one has to be carefully examine and changed accordingly to make sure the reference is correct. 
Once I added an extra column to my data table, I had to go through every cell and every formula, name ranges, conditional formatting, and change the reference.
Surely there must be a way without using VBA to start counting from zero without needing to manually change a reference every time it moves.

I've tried variations of `sum(row()-1+row()), mod, gcd`. could there be a way to have an absolute reference move with a cell?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is too basic, but why not use something like `=IF(ISNUMERIC(A1),A1+1,0)`? If you place that in A2, A3, etc. or B1, C1, etc. you get your series. That would only fail if, of course, the adjacent cell has a number, but perhaps that's not your case and this will work for you anyway.

Comment: I guess the real question here is: if you want in **one** static cell an incremental number then type this number in that cell.  Yet, who / what will determine when to increment that number? I'd guess that there is a list of all past IDs and what the current ID is. Then you can just get the maximum ID from the list with something like this `Max("A:A")`. But if you don't have any such list then you'll have to track and type these numbers yourself (manually). If you want this step automated then you'll not get around using VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured it out! i can't believe the answer eluded me for so long!

columns($A$1:a1)-1

This will give me a result of zero, and increments when filled across.
0   1   2   3   ...

rows($A$1:a1)-1 will do the same for rows.

I know it references a cell, but this way it doesn't matter which cell this formula is placed into, the result will always be the same. However if you insert of delete cells, just refill the formula through the desired cells.

I think this will be much easier than column()-column($A$1).
Thanks guys for your help.